# Universal Link configured but not working

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I’ve done everything that appears to be required to get Apple’s Deep Universal Links working, but when I test the URL from Notes or dragging the link from Air Drop to a device running my app that supports the universal link, it is opened in Safari and the delegate method is not called:

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
    NSLog(@"application openURL: %@", url);
    return true;
}
```

I have added my domain to the App Transport Security exception (in the Signing & Capabilities tab):

```
applinks:MyDomain.com?mode=developer
```

(MyDomain.com is a working domain name with https support)

[image]

I have ‘Associated Domains’ enabled for my app identifier and using the App ID Prefix shown for the app identifier used by my app Bundle Identifier.

My `apple-app-site-association` file:

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "details": [
           {
             "appIDs": [ "MyAppIdentifer.MyBundleIdentifer" ],
             "paths": [
                "*"
             ],
             "components": [
               {"/": "/*"}
             ]
           }
       ]
   }
}
```

The `apple-app-site-association` file is installed and visible were Apple requires it:

```
https://<fully qualified domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
```

And I validated `apple-app-site-association` using my app identifier, bundle identifier and my domain name here https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/

[image]

When I check Apple’s CDN, a stale copy of my `apple-app-site-association` is shown (that is missing the App Identifier):

```
curl https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/MyDomain.com

{
  "applinks": {
      "details": [
           {
             "appIDs": [ "MyBundleIdentifer" ],
             "paths": [
                "*"
             ],
             "components": [
               {"/": "/*"}
             ]
           }
       ]
   }
}
```

But since I’m using the applinks `mode=developer flag`, and running the app in debug mode, it should be getting the `apple-app-site-association` direct from my domain name. Anyways, it shows that my `apple-app-site-association` file is visible to Apple's server.

Comment: In the developer menu of your iPhone, make sure you have enabled "associated domains development". Why did you add your domain to the ats exception domains?  That is not required. The domain needs to be in the "associated domains" entitlement https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains

Comment: Thanks, yes I have enabled Associated Domains Development in the settings, I should have mentioned that. But I think you've pointed out what I've done wrong! That is almost certainly it - trying now thank you!

Comment: Interesting! Now in Notes I have the option to open the link in my App, and when I choose my app, it is now running the `continueUserActivity` delegate method and works! If you write your comment as an answer I will gladly accept it. I used Exception domains because that was already added and looked similar - doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your domain to the "associated domains" entitlement, not the ATS exception domains entitlement.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON file on your server has errors, that prevents the Apple CDN pick it up correctly.

You can check this, along with the time to take Apple CDN re-parse your file, just inspecting the headers of the https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/MyDomain.com request.

[image: Chrome Inspector]